# Div 100% size of viewport?

Tags: html, viewport

iv'e been looking for a way to making divs the same height and with as the users browser size, i fell over this: http://forum.webflow.com/t/code-tutorial-full-window-site/356/7
i want to achieve this effect: http://www.katieplusluke.com splitting my page up in section of diffrent colors ;)

With my very limited jquery/javascript knowledge, i tried it in a JSFiddle.

But i can't seem to make it work, so i figured that some genius in here, had the solution for me ;)

```
heres my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kj20ytue/6/
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine - you need to import the jquery library. Here's an updated fiddle

```
jsfiddle.net/kj20ytue/7/
```

Comment: ohhh.... how do i make it work on my own page then I've placed the jquery in a <script></script> tag and then the html and css where it has to be ;)

And this in my html head: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>



#edit it works now.

Comment: I got it working, do you have any suggestions how to place a div in the center of the div that is 100% of the viewport ;) i cant seem to make that happen :P